# how to fill the value in the pytorch tensor given the four coordinates of rotated box

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, matrix, pytorch

For a tensor with shape [bs, 1, h, w] filled with zero, i have four coordinates of a rotated box as shown in image
[rotated box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9Nem.png)

Now i want to fill the region occupied by the box with 1, is there any easy method to achive this?

Comment: Removed the opencv tag as it seems unrelated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @wohlstad, i update the description of the question, i think we may need opencv to solve this problem now

Answer (score 0):

You can find the upper-left and lower-right corners of the box and fill the tensor inside this box with 1s using the broadcasting ability of PyTorch.

```
import torch

# Create a tensor
bs = 2
h = 100
w = 100
x = torch.zeros(bs, 1, h, w)

box = [[1, 0], [10, 0], [10, 10], [1, 10]]

# Given the coordinates of the rectangle, make the rectangle full with 1s
def make_rect(x, box):
    rect_x0 = box[0][0]
    rect_y0 = box[0][1]
    rect_x1 = box[2][0]
    rect_y1 = box[2][1]
    x[:, :, rect_y0:rect_y1, rect_x0:rect_x1] = 1
    return x

make_rect(x, box)
```

Comment: Thanks for your relpy! I want to konw, if a rotated box is given (i update an image in the question), how could i achive this?